# Adaptation of ROMS for other devices

Tags: custom-roms, rom

Could I install certain custom ROMS for other devices e.g. Samsung tab 3 Stock on Samsung Galaxy tab 2? If so, how, and what should I do?

Comment: Shortly: You can't, all those devices are somewhat different in hardware (CPU, GPU, storage controller etc.)  and storage (partition layout, storage size etc.). Sometimes ROMs are ported from one device over to another if *most* of the hardware is the same or uses the same drivers. Other than that it's close to impossible to install ROMs designed for other devices. You *can* (given enough knowledge on the process) build your own custom ROM from sources (CM for instance).

Comment: @GiantTree aww. Well,  I could I rebuild CM to make it a later version of Android?

Comment: If you can get your hands on kernel sources and drivers for *at least* your chipset (CPU+mainboard) you could get a working ROM in some sort of pre-alpha state.

Comment: @GiantTree Well,  I have the whole system stored on a server (literally created a copy of / and stored it online) and I believe I am using the Samsung piranha chipset.

Comment: You are lucky, Samsung *usually* hosts the kernel sources public on their servers, sorted by device and firmware revision: http://opensource.samsung.com/

Comment: @GiantTree talk about convenient, eh?